# What do you call the top nav menu as used by Oracle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

The top nav menu as used by [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/index.html) displays a lot of links in an organized fashion.  I need to replicate this functionality.  So, I'd like to search for it but I do not know what this type of menu system is called.

If you can tell me the name or better yet some examples that I can use to replicate this menu, that would be even better.

javascript or jQuery solutions are acceptable.  Needs to be able to support IE ***preferably*** without the use of an HTC file but an HTC file is okay.

Comment: it's like a mega menu or super menu or some like this : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/megaMenu.jsf

Comment: That looks good but I don't know what .jsf extension is :blush:

Comment: @onheiron if you will put in an answer of megamenu or supermenu, I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: http://jaspreetchahal.org/5-best-jquery-css3-navigational-mega-menus/  - just adding a great one that is free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be a Mega Menu or Super Menu.

You can obtain that using Java facelets like [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/megaMenu.jsf) or go through [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) or Java Script Frameworks to help you bild one with javascript.

Comment: Marking correct as it answers the question of what it is called.

Answer (score 2):

This css3 mega menu bar could be useful for you. It is browser crossover

http://themes.pixelworkshop.fr/?theme=CSS3MegaMenu

Only needs css hardcode

Comment: It also has the same glaring usability issues as any pure CSS menu, although at least it's not multilevel.

Comment: I upped yours since you provided a great link